# Plots all red and green

Tags: matlab, plot, colors, matlab-figure

I seem to have made some settings change where all of my MATLAB plots (`plot`, `plot3`, `surf`, etc) show up in this red/green color scale:

[image: plot output]

I searched around forums and the MATLAB user guide but am not finding anything. It's not a huge deal, as I can enter code to fix this on each plot, but I shouldn't have to.

How to fix this?

Comment: Check `startup.m` you seem to have set your default `colorbar` to autumn or something. Just put it back to either `jet` (pre 2015a), or `parula`

Comment: @Adriaan - yeah, this (jet) fixed it. It still isn't the Matlab default for surf plots but it is for the rest of the plots. I had created a startup.m so that I wouldn't have to re-enter a path variable every time; turns out, that may reset other variables. Post your comment as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about the whole settings. These two commands can reset a figure properties (including its **colormap**) to its default values:

```
h=gcf;
reset(h)
```

This way you assign a handle to the last figure you have. Then, the second command resets its options to default values.

Update after Adrian's comment: Check out this page: [Default Property Values](https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/default-property-values.html) It clearly shows how is it possible to regenrate the problem you have and you might need use the `remove` option for removing user-defined default value. There is a factory defined colormap accessible by the function: `get(groot,'factoryFigureColormap')`. This might help you too.

Comment: If you changed your `colormap` in your `startup.m` file, won't it just reset the colours to whatever was specified there? I.e. it will stay another map.

Answer (score 1):

Check `startup.m` you seem to have set your default `colormap` to `autumn` or something. Just put it back to either `jet` (pre 2015a), or `parula`.